# How to block third party party JS using chrome profile 'managed_javascript_blocked_for_urls'

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, chrome-options

I have an automation suite running on an e-commerce website, which has a lot of third party JS content I do not want to load while running my tests. 
I am looking for ways to block the unwanted content on the website to reduce the page load time.

I was able to block images using the following block of code

```
{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  acceptInsecureCerts: true,
  chromeOptions: {
    'prefs': {
      'profile': {
         'default_content_setting_values': {
            'images': 2,
          },
       },
     },
   }
}
```

However, when I try to pass the the URLs I want to block using `'managed_javascript_blocked_for_urls'`, it does not work. This is how I tried passing the values to this flag:

`'default_javascript_blocked_for_urls': [ "www.googletagservices.com" ]`
`'managed_javascript_blocked_for_urls': [ "www.googletagservices.com" ]`
`'default_javascript_blocked_for_urls': { "www.googletagservices.com" : 2 }`

However, none of those combinations worked. Anyone who has used this with webdriverIO and would be able to help?